# why can't input anythin on the console when run my python code?

Tags: python

Why i got nothing output when run the following code?

```
def add(a,b):
    return(a+b)

if __name__=="__mani__":    
    fs_path=input("where do you want to save your data?")
    print(fs_path)
```

There is no output "where do you want to save your data?" in the console ,
i can not inuput value to fs_path,and no print output.

Comment: You have a typo: `"__mani__"` should be `"__main__"`

Comment: when i revise it into *"__main__"* ,it is ok.it is a bug or not when the statement is wrong.  *if __name__=="__mani__":*  ,no message about error  happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Your

```
if __name__=="__mani__":
```

Should be

```
if __name__=="__main__":
```

Answer (score 0):

One:
`__mani__` should probable be `__main__`
Two:
if >python3.0 I believe you have to use `raw_input()`